# During segregation and Jim Crow laws in the US what happened if a person was allowed to use white facilities but other users objected?

Tags: united-states, racism

In Nazi Germany everything was formal and on paper, whatever you looked even if you were in yermulke, if you had a paper allowing you to go somewhere and do something, no-one could object. But what happened in the USA during the Jim Crow laws? What would happen if someone was initially allowed to use the facilities for whites but then someone would raise objections?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786) What is "Yermulke"? (not, AFAICT, an English word) Consequences would have depended on state law and local custom.

Comment: If a black person was allowed to use the facility, then it wasn't  a "facility for whites".

Comment: @DJClayworth I meant aperson whose whiteness could be contested.

Comment: So what you are really asking is "who decided if somebody is black or not"?

Comment: @DJClayworth yes, and what were their enforcement powers against those who disagreed.

Comment: This is where the [one drop rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-drop_rule) intersects with the concept of [passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passing_(racial_identity)#Passing_for_white).

Comment: "I meant a person whose whiteness could be contested" It doesn't say that in your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to address the comments and avoid closure

Answer (score 3):

First, let me note that your characterization of Nazi policies is misleading. They did have the semblance of rules with the [Nuremberg Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_Laws#Classifications_under_the_laws), but they did not always follow their own rules, and both physical appearance and behaviour of their victims did play a significant part in that. Someone who did not meet their racial definition of a Jew, but dressed like a traditionalist Jew, would be persecuted along with them.

As to your main question, events like the [arrest of Rosa Parks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_Parks#Refusal_to_move) did ultimately involve the police, but they started out with enforcement attempts by people like the bus driver. Another passenger would likely have complained to the bus driver first. The driver may or may not side with the bully. For a victim whose appearance was more ambiguous than that of Rosa Parks, much would depend on how the "white community" on the bus or in the bar or whereever would react. Clothing and accent of the victim would likely matter a lot, and so would the question if the victim was personally known to any bystanders.

Comment: Another such thing we have really good records of is segreated lunch counters. First line of enforcement was employees there. Ultimately if the person refused, police would be called. In between, the person breaking the rules could expect to be terrorized by common citizens, including assault and battery. If they were identified personally, their families, houses, or place of worship might later be violently targeted. Typical terrorist tactics.